# Net Core API HttpPost with int array parameter

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

I am building application and one of the features is to provide ids so it could be later processed by API.
I have created another Net Core API HttpPost method, like below:

```
    [HttpPost("addapplication")]
    public IActionResult AddApplication([FromBody] int[] invoiceIds)
    {
        int newApplicationId = _applRepository.AddApplication(invoiceIds);

        if (newApplicationId == 0)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        ClientApplicationDto applicationData = GetApplication(newApplicationId);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetApplication", new { newApplicationId }, applicationData);
    }
```

Pretty similar to how I built another `HttpPost`.
However when trying to check it with Postman with below body:

```
{
   "invoiceIds": [5, 6]
}
```

I get error:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|f14e8651-4e050cec0f913d32.",
    "errors": {
        "$": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32[]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well anwser was simple as wrong formulated JSON:

```
[5,6]
```